# Broadcasting UDP from within a Docker container

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I've just started experimenting with Docker and have hit an issue I haven't been able to resolve (please note, I'm using boot2docker).

My container has a simple service that listens on **8080/tcp** and **5000/udp**.

> docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:5000:5000/udp -p 0.0.0.0::8080 test/service

From my macos terminal, I can telnet to 192.168.59.103:8080 and issue simple commands, so TCP is working fine.

Next, I try UDP by issuing the following:

> echo "HELLO" | socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.59.103:5000,broadcast

via Wireshark, I can see the datagram making it to the service and the service tries to echo it back, but receives an ICMP response stating the port is invalid.

So it seems I'm pretty close to having a working test case, but I'm just not sure what I need to configure to allow the broadcast back to the mac terminal that initiated the call.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please disregard this question.  I misinterpreted the wireshark output and was able to track the issue down to my service config.

Comment: where you able to udp broadcast from your service after all?